# Jackson unable to deserialize immutable object with enum field

Tags: java, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

Spring Boot 2.5.4 with Jackson 2.12.4

Given the following simplified enum...

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum PaymentMethod {
  CREDITCARD(1);

  private long id;
}
```

... and a request object which shall be deserialized using Jackson:

```java
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class PaymentRequest {

    @JsonProperty(value = "paymentMethod")
    private PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
}
```

This works just fine. Now, I'd like to make the request object immutable, so I changed it to this:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class PaymentRequest {

    @JsonProperty(value = "paymentMethod")
    private final PaymentMethod paymentMethod;
}
```

But this variant fails:

`Cannot construct instance of 'PaymentRequest' (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)`

Is this some Jackson limitation when deserializing enums?

Comment: What is the Spring Boot version used?

Comment: I'm on Spring Boot 2.5.4 with Jackson 2.12.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue not because parameter is an `Enum`, its because `Lombok` and `Jackson` doesn't work together in this scenario.

When deserializing to an immutable class, we need to explicitly mention that with `Jackson` annotation. Usually we annotate the constructor. But in this case the constructor is created by `Lombok` and `Lombok` do not add those annotation.

The easy fix is, remove `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation and create constructor yourself. Then annotate constructor as `@JsonCreator`. Something like this,

```
@Getter
public class PaymentRequest {

    @JsonProperty(value = "paymentMethod")
    private final PaymentMethod paymentMethod;

    @JsonCreator
    public PaymentRequest(PaymentMethod paymentMethod) {
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }
}
```